# style priority not working as expected in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have the following scss styles defined in a separate file

```
.radio-button-focused {
  background-color: $PURPLE;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 1;
  width: px-to-rem(1248px);
  margin-bottom: px-to-rem(15px);
  @include truncate;
}

.radio-button {
  background-color: $BLACK;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 1;
  width: px-to-rem(1248px);
  margin-bottom: px-to-rem(15px);
  @include truncate;
}
```

Both of them are being applied to a button

But the problem is that radio button is overwritting the color of radio-button-focused

I understand that I could use !important , or just use one of them instead of using them both at the same time. But if I was forced to use both, can something else be done to fix this?

Comment: The answer from @David may well be it, but I'd also ask why you're not using the `:focus` selector ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)) to style a focused element. It's more specific and thus less likely to go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal order in the CSS file matters. If two rules have the same specificity, the last one is applied. Move `.radio-button` before `.radio-button-focused`. You could also make your focused selector more specific. `.radio-button.radio-button-focused` for example.

Here's class B before A as an example.

```css
.b
{
  color: red;
}

.a
{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">Hi</div>
```

And here's A before B.

```css
.a
{
  color: blue;
}

.b
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">Hi</div>
```

Comment: It's CSS 101 @mouchin777,  you should learn about css "cascading" and specificity before even thinking about using `!important`.